# Executing Navigator.pop() when key pad is visible results in render flex error

Tags: flutter

I have noticed creating forms with flutter. That if there is Scaffold with a text field focused i.e the key pad visible if one presses the back button.

```
Navigator.pop();
```

This results in an render flex error.

I have tried wrapping the child in the single child scroll view components also tried setting the resize to avoid bottom padding property to true. 
I still get the error.

Has anyone else experienced this ?
if so what is the solution and cause of the error ?

EDIT:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Settings",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: primaryColor,
            fontFamily: titleFontStyle
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: primaryColor),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 10.0,
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 60.0, 20.0, 0.0),
        child: SettingsForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SettingsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsFormState createState() => _SettingsFormState();
}

class _SettingsFormState extends State<SettingsForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form( 
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Username',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            RaisedButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 40.0),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: primaryColor,
              child: Text(
                'Update',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your form fields are in listview?

Comment: Yeah..It was column first but I changed it but the problem persists did you try replicating it ???

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that when I navigate back to the previous component. It was the previous component that overflowed.

I had used Column in the said component.

Converting it into ListView solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that, and it works fine. The keyboard layout will close when you press back button and navigate you to previous page.

Here is my 2 dart files below:

main.dart (From which I navigating through)

```
import 'settings.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new HomeScreen()
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: new Center(child: new Text("Click Mee")),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: () {
          print("Clicked");
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SettingsForm()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

settings.dart (your provided code on next screen)

```
class SettingsForm extends StatefulWidget {

  SettingsForm();

  @override
  _SettingsFormState createState() => _SettingsFormState();
}

class _SettingsFormState extends State<SettingsForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Color primaryColor = const Color.fromRGBO(3, 155, 226, 1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Settings",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: primaryColor
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: primaryColor),
          onPressed: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            print("yes");
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 10.0,
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 60.0, 20.0, 0.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Username',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 40.0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: primaryColor,
                  child: Text(
                    'Update',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your app is closing on that back button? Is it like that? Means do you want that? or there is some other page on which this page is navigating through?

Comment: The app doesn't exit on back button ...it only navigates back to another widget.

Comment: It was not occurring on my side, Sadly, Don't know what you are facing though?

Comment: I have fixed the error... It only happens if the Widget we are going back to is a Column based...It doesn't depend on the current Widget  ...I turned it into a ListView and it works fine.

Comment: I have told you, there is nothing wrong on this screen's code.